# Starcraft 2 Ladder games 3v3?

Tags: starcraft-2

I don't get how the ladder system in StarCraft 2 works. I mean, I understand that I am placed in a ladder position according to my rank, but how do we start a 3v3 ladder game? There seems to be no option for that.

Or do I have to play through 1v1 and/or 2v2 a number of games before I get access to 3v3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot *start* a 3v3 or 4v4 while you are still in practice league (but you can still play in one!).

Either have someone else create *(right-click their portrait and choose 'set as party leader')*, or press the "skip" button to remove yourself from the practice league *(once removed you cannot rejoin it)*.

Comment: @McKay: While in practice league, there is no option for 3v3 (only 1v1 and 2v2), even if there are three people in your party. Based on the OP's question, this sounds like his problem.  Where do you see that he's in a 1v1 league?

Comment: Correct, I was in practice league.

Answer (score 3):

You are ranked separately in your 3v3 from your ranking in 1v1.  What's more if you have a full team (which in 3v3 is a party of 3) then that ranking is separate from all others.

However, if you have a less than full team, your ranking will be 3s Random (which means 3v3 with at least 1 member being random), and is separate from any full team ranking.

For example you can have:

- 1s: Diamond 30
- 2 Random: Diamond 50
- 2s tzenes and McKay: Diamond 20
- 2s tzenes and BlueRaja: Gold 2
- 3 Random: Plat 10
- 3s tzenes, McKay, BlueRaja: Gold 20

All of these ranks are seperate, but if I play a 3s game with just McKay and I that contributes to my 3 Random ranking.

To start a match in 3v3 by yourself you would would select the 3v3 button on the multiplayer screen (here is an image I'll find a better one when I get home):

[image]

Comment: I think you and I could make it to at least platinum together :)

Comment: @BlueRaja in this example I d/c'd on one of our placement matches and we have yet to lose more than 2 games so the system won't bump us up yet, even though we're beating top 10 Diamond players :D