# How do ladders work in StarCraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

Well the question pretty much sums it up. I'm currently in the bronze league, and I'm wondering around when I'll get to the silver league or if there's anything that I have to do. I haven't found much info on the Internet.

Also, as a bronze league player, do I ever play with silver league players?

Comment: A related StarCraft 2 question, though this one is about game types rather than leagues: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5753/starcraft-2-ladder-games-3v3

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5763/starcraft-2-divisions

Comment: As a high-Gold League player i played several times against bronze league, usually at times where no sane person in my region is usually online. It seems SC2 favors people from the same league but if it can't find someone it extends the search (i think it says that as a message when searching) to include lower leagues. The less people online, the lower the chance to get someone from your league.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To move to a higher league, you have to simply play well, win matches and rank high in your league. Then you might be promoted to a higher league. Same goes with demoting - play bad, get to the bottom of the ladder and you will be demoted to a lower league.

When playing matches, you might encounter players from almost any league i think. I personaly am ranked in a platinum league and played a few matches with gold or silver ranked players. You will see that sometimes the load screen reads "Slightly favored" or "Favored" above you or the oponent. That means one of you is considered better and the game thinks he/you should win.

Comment: Actually the "Favored"/"Slightly favored" is based on some hidden metric. I had an "Even" match playing against Gold (I was Bronze at that time, now Silver), and had a match against a Bronze player (when in Silver) and he was "Slightly favored".