# Starcraft II Ladder Matches(How to get promoted)

Tags: starcraft-2

I recently started playing starcraft II and was originally placed in Silver League. After playing various matches winning half and losing half or so I got demoted to Bronze League, personally at the time I didn't mind because I wanted to learn the game the right way, etc. However, I only played 6 or so games before being demoted, I have been in Bronze league for a month or so now and have maintained a rank 3 or so during this period and I constantly play with Silver players, etc,(and won) and I have still not been promoted. I had a winning streak of 10 matches and no promotions, yet I was demoted in the first 10 games.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do ladders work in StarCraft 2?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6234/how-do-ladders-work-in-starcraft-2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most comprehansive guide about SC2 ladder is [here](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=195273) (I belive)

As for your question "when will I be promoted": just keep playing and you'll get it. Especially if you constantly see opponents from higher league.

> By outperforming the rest of your league, it is possible to get
>   promoted into a higher league. If you are in Bronze but playing
>   against Gold players, you would expect to be promoted to Gold, but
>   that doesn't always happen immediately.
>
> This is because the system requires a certain degree of confidence
>   before players can be moved to a new league, otherwise they would
>   bounce around from league to league too frequently for leagues to be
>   meaningful.

FYI: Blizzard support will not answer you if you call them about ladder "issue".

Comment: Thanks, I have been constantly playing with Gold members for a while now hopefully I'll be promoted.

Comment: Moving up in leagues fast can prevent promotion, too. If you are bronze and get matched with golds while still winning most matches, the system gives you a low confidence on your position until you start hitting the "~50% winrate barrier". As soon as you start losing more, the confidence will rise and you might then skip silver league and go directly into gold league.

Answer (score 1):

The exact mechanics of league placement are a secret held eagerly by Blizzard. However, folks have guessed parts of it rather accurately. You can read about what we know on [Liquipedia](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Battle.net_Leagues).